# java unzipping files with folders

Tags: java, netbeans, zip

First of all, I didn't see any other question that helps me 'directly' with my problem, that's why I decided to create a new one.

The following code is programmed to unzip multiple files and folders.

```
try {
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    CheckedInputStream checksum = new CheckedInputStream(fis, new Adler32());
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(checksum));
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            String rutaarchivo = entry.getName();
            int index= rutaarchivo.lastIndexOf('/');
            rutaarchivo=rutaarchivo.substring(index+1);

            estado.setText("Estado: Copiando archivos nuevos: " + entry);
            setProgress(60);
            int zipCounter = 0;
            int count;
            int BUFFER = 2048;
            byte datazip[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(rutaarchivo);
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = zis.read(datazip, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                dest.write(datazip, 0, count);
                zipCounter += count;
                progreso.setValue(zipCounter);
            }
            dest.flush();

            dest.close();
        }
    }
    zis.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    PrintStream outprint = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(outprint);
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    PrintStream outprint = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(outprint);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    PrintStream outprint = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(outprint);
}
```

This code is working right but has an important mistake: it does uncompress folders, but instead of showing them like this:

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt
- folder/file4.txt
- folder/file5.txt
- folder/file6.txt

It shows this:

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt
- file4.txt
- file5.txt
- file6.txt

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the name of the file in the `FileOutputStream` to just the file name.

```
String rutaarchivo = entry.getName();
int index= rutaarchivo.lastIndexOf('/');  // removes directory path
rutaarchivo=rutaarchivo.substring(index+1); // removes directory path
...
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(rutaarchivo);
```

This is a bad idea. You should make your own base file path and append a file name to that.

Comment: so if I delete the lines that "remove directory path" would it be solved?

Comment: @Sebastian96 Solved depends on what you are trying to do. It'll keep the path as it appears in the ZIP file. It might be safer to build this path yourself.

Comment: OK. Removing the lines does not help, it throws a FileNotFoundException

Comment: @Sebastian96 Do you understand what happens when you remove them? Try to put a `System.out.println(rutaarchivo)` to see what file you are trying to create.